# After deleting more than one cell uitableview adds some rows

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am using "swipe to delete" and if I want to delete more than one cell in a sequence, some cells in uitableview get doubled or some already deleted cells appear. Because I can't post any images I will describe behavior of the table:

1. Table before cell deletion: User1, User2, User3, User4, User5, Add new user.
2. Table after deletion of User1 and User5: User2, User3, User4, Add new user, **Add new user** (but is not selectable).
3. Table after deletion of User3: User4, User2, Add new user, **User5** (selectable), **Add new user** (not selectable).

Method where I am deleting cells looks like:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
      [self.usersTable beginUpdates];
      UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[self.usersTable cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
      NSString *userNameToDelete = cell.textLabel.text;
      // Data source
      [self.appDict removeObjectForKey:userNameToDelete];
      self.arrayOfUserNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.appDict allKeys]];
      [self.appDict writeToFile:self.pathOfAppFile atomically:YES];
      // Deleting cell
      [self.usersTable deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath]  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
      [self.usersTable endUpdates];
   }
}
```

Method to support editing:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (indexPath.row == [self.arrayOfUserNames count]) {
   return NO;
}
else {
   return YES;
}
```

Number of rows in section:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
   return [self.arrayOfUserNames count] + 1;
}
```

I have already tried with [self.usersTable reload] but everything stays the same. I have also tried changing the size of the table in numberOfRowsInSection: but that too is not helping. Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

haven´t you implemented

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        //delete your user record
    }    
}
```

?

if not the Tableview will remove the cell but the underlying data will not be modified and it results in such a strange behaviour.

**edit:**

try to use:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

      NSString *userNameToDelete = [[self arrayOfUserNames] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
      // Data source
      [self.appDict removeObjectForKey:userNameToDelete];
      self.arrayOfUserNames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithArray:[self.appDict allKeys]];
      [self.appDict writeToFile:self.pathOfAppFile atomically:YES];

      [tableView reloadData];


   }
}
```

to give a short explanation:

when

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

is called, the tablecell was deleted from the tableview, so you don´t have to handle this. If you do it you´ll remove the next cell.

Comment: I changed self.usersTable to tableView in that method, but behavior stays the same. Did you have this in mind?

Comment: oh sorry. seems I´m a bit blinded ;)

Comment: I assume [tableview reloadData] didn't work correctly because table or view itself sees no need to redraw itself after deleting more than one cell in a sequence. Upon your suggestion I changed self.userstable in commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath: to tableview (and left unchanged everything else) and now it works.